# ¿Por qué puedo cambiar el significado de private a public?

Tags: c++, c++11

Hoy intenté este código

*fuente.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>

#define private public
#include "cabecera.hpp"
#undef private

int main()
{
  claseCualquiera datos;
  std::cout << datos.dato_privado << "!\n";
}
```

*cabecera.hpp*

```
struct claseCualquiera {
   private: int dato_privado = 1234;
};
```

Luego corrí desde la linea de comandos:

```
$ g++ fuente.cpp -o salida -std=c++11; ./salida
1234
```

Fue una sorpresa porque yo esperaba algún tipo de error. Nunca creí que funcionaría.

¿Por que me permitió el compilador (o pre-compilador) modificar el significado de una palabra reservada? En este caso `private` fue claramente cambiada como `public` y logré acceder a un miembro privado.

¿Es intencional o accidental? ¿Esto significa que puedo acceder a miembros privados de clases que están en otras librerías del sistema?

Por si sirve de algo, esta es la versión de mi compilador.

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: ¿Por qué puedo entrar en una estancia en la que pone "prohibido el paso"? Porque no hay nada que te impida usar tus medios (piernas) para hacer algo que no debes: sólo tu concepto de adhesión a las normas. Tampoco hay nada que te impida usar las herramientas a tu alcance para cambiar `private` por `public` ni `class` por `struct` ni `int` por `double`, sólo el hecho de que "*sabes que no está bien*".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Funciona así porque el preprocesador de C es el que (pre)procesa los directivos que empiezan con `#`. Es como si fuera otro programa distinto — y de hecho, lo puede ser.

Por eso el compilador no sabe, ni puede saber, lo que has hecho con tu código fuente antes de pasarlo al compilador.

Y sí, esto sí es intencional. Siempre ha funcionado de esta manera.  Sólo tú puedes decidir si vas a usar este gran poder — o si vas a abusarlo. :)

Comment: queria pegar la captura de la linea pre-procesada de g++ pero no es tan clara,  muy buena respuesta

Comment: `#define true false` es un ejemplo bastante típico de lo fácil que es abusar de esta herramienta (y de por qué se procura reemplazar por otras construcciones propias de cada lenguaje en lugar de usar un preprocesador genérico)